# Calculating Roll, Pitch and Yaw from angles

Tags: javascript, vector, 3d, game-physics

I am working on a simulation of an aircraft with three axes of motion (roll, pitch and yaw).
I have the roll angle (number of degrees the wings are tilted about the nose-tail axis of the aircraft), pitch angle (angle between the nose and the horizon) and yaw angle (the compass heading of the aircraft).

What I am trying to determine is the unit vector of lift (ie. the vector which is "up" from the aircraft) - ie. when the aircraft is straight and level the vector for lift should point straight up, when the aircraft's nose is straight up the lift vector is given by `180 - roll_angle`, etc.

I have made partial progress with only two angles (eg. roll and yaw) by simply taking the spherical co-ords of the new point and converting to cartesian and taking the normal to the plane given by the resultant vector. However, I am unsure how to take into account the third angle (pitch).

What I am looking to achieve is a function which accepts the three angles (roll, pitch and yaw) and gives the unit vector of lift.

```
function get_lift_vector()
{
    var lift_vector_heading = 0;
    var lift_vector_elevation = 90;

    // Adjust to range (-180, 180]
    roll_angle %= 360;
    if(roll_angle > 180)
    {
        roll_angle = 180 - roll_angle;
    }

    // Roll
    if(roll_angle > 0)
    {
        lift_vector_heading = 90;
        lift_vector_elevation = 90 - roll_angle;
    }
    else if(roll_angle < 0)
    {
        lift_vector_heading = 270;
        lift_vector_elevation = 90 - roll_angle;
    }

    // Yaw
    lift_vector_heading += aircraft_compass_heading;
    lift_vector_heading %= 360;

    // Pitch

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved this problem using the ThreeJS library's implementation of Euler angles after posting a related question over at Math SE where [Matti P.'s detailed answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3394479/rotating-an-axis-system-in-3d/3394559#3394559) provided the necessary mathematical background.

Essentially, the problem becomes an intrinsic Euler angle problem, whereby we avoid the inelegant pseudocode I posted above and simply plug in the relevant angles, then transform the original z-axis unit vector (which is the vector of lift), the resultant vector is the unit vector of lift.

I am including a snippet of code using the ThreeJS library's `Math` package which nicely takes care of the actual mathematics behind the Euler angle transformation.

```
var transform = 
    new Euler(_Math.degToRad(angle_of_attack),
    _Math.degToRad(roll_angle),
    _Math.degToRad(heading),
    'ZXY');

var v = new Vector3(0, 0, 1);
v.applyEuler(transform);

return [v.x, v.y, v.z];
```